# Sum the time based on criteria multiple in and out

Tags: microsoft-excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFJCa.jpg)this is my first post requesting how to find net working hours for an employee based on their in and out on a multiple times per day. Employees start their shifts in different times based on call out. 
Much appreciated, if some one able to give suggestions. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply take all of the *Out* times and subtract all if the *In* times, you will get the total time spent.

Caveat: There **must** be a matching *Out* Time for every *In* time. You might want to create a warning (possibly a CFR) to show when there isn't. The time format in E3:F3 should also be like `[hh]:mm:ss` so that *>24hrs* is clearly visible.

Put the following formula into E3 and fill right.

```
=SUMIFS($A:$A, INDEX($B:$C, , MATCH(E$2, $B$1:$C$1, 0)), "out")-
 SUMIFS($A:$A, INDEX($B:$C, , MATCH(E$2, $B$1:$C$1, 0)), "in")
```

I've made the formula truly dynamic so you won't have to change anything when dragging right.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, You are legend. The formula full-fill best way to calculate  the working hours.