# Macro code or formula to calculate the difference between two alternative cells (loop)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a macro code or formula to return the total elapsed time from multiple in and out using current time.(See attached image)[image]

Here I am calculating the time difference between out time- in time to find staff field hours and  also Im alerting the field staff if he spent more than 6 hrs in the field  using  rolling time(Current time -in time). But My formula returns error, if there is no value in In time. could you please suggest any solution?. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum the time based on criteria multiple in and out](https://superuser.com/questions/1533009/sum-the-time-based-on-criteria-multiple-in-and-out)

Comment: Sorry, both my questions are different